Send all Exceptions/Console/Sl4j logs to Graylog
I have a logback-spring.xml file like:
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%green(%date) %highlight(%-5level) %yellow([%file:%line]) %blue(: %msg%n)</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <SpringProfile name="dev">
        <springProperty scope="context" name="port" source="graylog.port"/>
        <springProperty scope="context" name="host" source="graylog.host"/>

        <appender name="GELF" class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfUdpAppender">
            <graylogHost>${host}</graylogHost>
            <graylogPort>${port}</graylogPort>
            <maxChunkSize>508</maxChunkSize>
            <useCompression>true</useCompression>
            <encoder class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfEncoder">
                <originHost>${host}</originHost>
                <includeRawMessage>false</includeRawMessage>
                <includeMarker>true</includeMarker>
                <includeMdcData>true</includeMdcData>
                <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
                <includeRootCauseData>true</includeRootCauseData>
                <includeLevelName>true</includeLevelName>
                <shortPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%m%nopex</pattern>
                </shortPatternLayout>
                <fullPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
                </fullPatternLayout>
                <staticField>app_name:graylog-spring</staticField>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <!--additivity provides single output by logger. Otherwise, root+logger provides duplicate logs-->
        <logger name="com.nar.hexademo" additivity="false">
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="GELF" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </logger>
    </SpringProfile>

</configuration>

and my purpose is send all console logs to Graylog but it only sends sl4j logs log.info("..."). Is there a way to send all console logs (especially exceptions) to Graylog?
When I specify it with log.error("...", ex);, it sends
try {}
catch (Exception ex) {
   log.error("...", ex);
}

But when I specify it without log like throw ex;, it doesn't send.
dependency:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.siegmar</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.gelf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

Related Issue: https://community.graylog.org/t/unable-to-see-stracktrace-in-graylog/24817

I have been suffering from this problem for a long time. The only thing I did:
I catched some exceptions inside Global Exception Handler class and use log.error("Exception", ex) to send exceptions to Graylog with their stack traces.
By the way I am using Spring Boot 3.2.3
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInternalException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    log.error("InternalException happened: ", ex);

    var stackTrace = isTraceOn(request) ? ExceptionUtil.getStackTrace(ex) : null;

    var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
        ex.getMessage(),
        stackTrace
    );

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

